# Why is 'C minor' parallel to 'E♭ major', but not to 'D♯ major'?

Tags: key

The way I have parallel keys in my head is that ***a major key is always three half-steps higher than a minor key***. I was trying to evaluate this on the circle of fifths and also during an exam, but I realized that at some point this can actually fail, namely when enharmonic spellings are at work.

For example, during an exam I was given the two following keys and was asked to write their parallels;

- C minor
- D♭ Major

What I did was to follow the principle I had in my head:

- C minor + 3 half-steps gives the parallel major key = D♯ major
- D♭ Major - 3 half-steps gives the parallel minor key = B♭ minor

So I failed in the first case. The correct answer is actually **E♭ major**.

But in the second case, did I succeed? B♭ minor is their on the circle of fifths, but A♯ is there too!!

[image]

I do not understand how this works. **Why is D♯ major wrong but E♭ major instead correct?** So why is the enharmonic spelling NOT there in case of E♭ major but it's there in case of B♭/A♯ minor?!

Comment: Just to be clear are you asking about relative or parallel minor keys here, they are different and based on your question it seems it is actually relative minors you are asking about.

Comment: D# is **not** Eb. Similarly, an augmented second is **not** a minor third. 

Also, the **relative** major key to a minor key isn't three half steps up, it's the major key starting on the third note of the minor scale - D# is not in the key of C minor.

Comment: @Walt - thanks for that. But on all of my keyboards, it is.And if I move up an aug 2nd, I end on the same key (note) as I do for a minor 3rd.. But I know what you're saying.

Comment: @Tim Theory != practice, which is why this site specifies that it's for both. In practice, with most instruments, you press the same buttons for D# and Eb and they make the same sound. When discussing music theory you need an slightly more abstract mindset than "which button on my instrument makes this sound" or even "what does this sound like". That was my point.

Comment: "D#-major" is not a key.

Comment: Due to differences in terminology in parts of the world, the header isn't accurately reflecting what OP is asking. The ***parallel*** key more genarally recognised is the major or minor which **has the same root**. This question will be more readily understood using the term ***relative***.

Comment: First of all, I'm downvoting this as "not useful". Second of all, C minor is NOT parallel to Eb major. Third of all, there is no D# major.

Answer (score 14):

It has to do with the idea of "Enharmonic equivalents".

You should have arrived at Eb flat major when you counted up in your head because that was the key you were in.  Had the note you were given been B#, you would have counted up to D# and it would have worked.

An enharmonic equivalent is when two notes are the same, that is played at the same spot, but have different names.

For example, D# and E-flat are enharmonic equivalents.

So, in your example,  The **key of E flat** has the following notes

Eb - F- G - Ab - Bb - C - D

And so the relative minor is C minor because (among other ways) you find the parallel minor by locating the sixth scale degree.

The relative minor **C minor** would have

C - D - Eb - F- G - Ab - Bb

The notes in the key of D# will contain notes which are the enharmonic equivalent to the notes in Eb.

D# - E# - Fx - G# - A# - B# - Cx

So the relative minor would be called B# minor.  So if you had been given the note B# you should have arrived at D# like you did.

If you spelled both these minor scales out you would be able to adjust the labels for the notes in a way that they both used the same notes.  They are spelled differently though just as is.

When you counted up **you switched flats and sharps** and that is why you arrived at D# instead of Eb. Counting up in C minor you should have used flats, if the note had been B# you would have used sharps.

Comment: It might be worth adding that while there's nothing technically incorrect about using the D# major scale, it should be clear why the enharmonic equivalent of Eb is preferred: three flats in the key signature instead of five sharps and two double sharps (!!).

Comment: @ToddWilcox: Aren't you missing the point? By your logic, the preferred relative major for B# minor would also be Eb.

Comment: @TonyK The problem is the *double* sharps, not the raw number of symbols in the key signature. Double sharps are exclusively restricted to accidentals in standard classical harmony.

Comment: Also, I think you should put stronger emphasis on the fact that the tonic of a relative key is always a scale degree in the original key.

Comment: @TonyK Maybe we are making two different points. My point is the preferred enharmonic spelling for B# minor is C minor because there are fewer accidentals in the key signature.

Comment: @KyleStrand "Double sharps are exclusively restricted to accidentals in standard classical harmony"? This is simply not true. It never happens (at least, I couldn't name an example), because re-enharmonizing the key would yield a key signature with much fewer flats/sharps, so this is usually preferred. But this is not a rule; it is perfectly possible to write a (part of a) piece in B# major, if you so desire.

Comment: @11684 "It never happens....But...it is perfectly possible"? That doesn't sound like a defense of "standard classical harmony" to me. Our "rules" of classical harmony are merely extrapolations from conventions followed by historical composers. Not putting double-sharps or double-flats in the key signature is one of those rules. (For a counter-example, though not one that really counts as "classical harmony", see Faeries' Aire and Death Waltz.)

Answer (score 12):

**These are NOT parallel, they're relative**.  Parallel keys both start on the **same** note/root.

The problem stems from not knowing the key sigs. C minor has the same key sig as Eb major. 3 flats. Not a sharp in sight, so D# couldn't be a good answer. Every key has 7 different letter names for the 7 different notes. Using your idea, go through C minor scale. C, D, D#, F, G. That is wrong - there's two 'D' names, and no 'E' name. So, we use Eb in preference. Much easier when stuff has to be written on staves.

In the Db case, you would succeed if the question asked for **relative** keys. Count up the scale - Db Eb F Gb Ab Bb C. 6th one up *is* Bb. Where was A#? Got knocked out by the A being Ab, so the B needed to be Bb. Pretty straightforward!

Comment: But note that, in German, one calls the relative key (that shares the same key signature) the *Paralleltonart*, whereas the parallel key (with the same tonic) is the *Varianttonart*.

Comment: @Richard - that's good information! And confusing! Possibly, if people used their profile space, we may be able to 'read between the lines' and help even more.  But the OP writes really good English, so don't think that's the problem here.  Seems to have thrown the question in, and not returned yet!

Comment: It's interesting how languages seem to be split between ones where it's "parallel" and ones where it's "relative". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_key#Terminology

Answer (score 4):

'Three half steps' is correct, as far as it goes.  The rest of the story is 'a minor third'.    Any interval of a third includes three letter-names.   So C, D, Eb rather than C, D, D#.

If you want more reasons, think what notes are in C minor scale, and in Eb major.  Plenty of identical spellings, yes?  So we spell it that way, not as D# minor.

Your 'Circle of 5ths' chart shows C# major as relative to A# minor, Db major as relative to Bb minor.  Though the layout might not make this completely clear, the two are not interchangable.  C# goes with A#, Db goes with Bb.

Want a way to remember it?  A Major in the army retires with a bit of loot and buys a diamond mine.  Of course, he needs to employ a Miner to do the digging.  When the Major needs to visit the Miner he goes DOWN three half-steps (it's a shallow mine).  Another name for this distance is a Minor Third.  Three notes, three letters.

Answer (score 4):

The basic answer is that standard keys do not have any double sharps or flats in them.

- The scale in D# major would be D#, E#, Fx, G#, A#, B#, Cx -- which contains two double sharps.  Therefore, only the enharmonic equivalent of Eb major, which contains no double flats or sharps, is allowed.
- The reason A# minor *is* allowed is that the natural minor scale for A# minor is A#, B#, C#, D#, E#, F#, G#, A# -- so seven sharps (!), but no double sharps or double flats.

A better rule than "three half steps" might be "a minor third".  This should always work -- for example, C minor -> Eb major, Bb minor -> Db major.

Comment: Trouble is, to a lot of folk, a min.3rd is synonymous with 3 half steps.

Comment: Well, then 'a lot of folk' need to up their game a bit!   The reason is not to avoid double sharps, but to maintain the 'minor third' relationship.    D# major is the relative major of B# minor.  There's no getting out of that from a music theory perspective.     Having said that, any composer who did find himself in that situation for more than a few notes would doubtless make an enharmonic 'leap of faith' and spell the notes less correctly but more conveniently!

Comment: While there may be strong imperatives to avoid double sharps or double flats in key signatures because such things will make performance difficult, from a music-theory perspective it would seem less icky to say that the parallel minor to Db major is Db minor (even though it would have eight flats) than to say that it's C# minor (which would require everything to be written a staff note lower) or that Db minor has no parallel minor key.

Answer (score 0):

You got the answer right the first time. Only change that I would do, to be 100% theoretically correct is to only use notes within given scale.

Cminor  (in this scale you don't have D# note but you do Eb).

It all comes down to circle of Fifths and Fourths.
Cminor comes from Circle of Fourths and within this circle we can Eb scale or chord.

So next time just follow this logic.

Answer (score 0):

any scales should be in CDEFGAB form,

c minor is theoretically written as: C,D,(Eb),F,G,(Ab),(Bb)

and not as: C,D,(D#),F,G,(Ab),(Bb)

in the wrong case you will have an extra D; D and D#.

the key is right but in theory the presentation is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The simple reason is that if D# Major were a key, it would have nine sharps. Meanwhile, D# Minor actually exists, and has six sharps.

You'll always get the right answer if you remember that one parallel key can't have sharps while the other has flats. C Minor has three flats, so its parallel major is also a flat key. D# Minor uses the same piano keys as both Gb Major and F# Major, but it is only parallel to F# Major, while Gb Major is parallel to Eb Minor.

Comment: You're right, sorry.